# Concatenar WHILE

Tags: php

Como posso concatenar um while para colocar em um array.
Como fazer essa parte de código funcionar?

```
$nestedData[] = $row["nomerota"];

                $tr="<select size='1'>";
                $tr.= while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) 
                {
                <option value='$row['nome'];'>$row['nome'];</option>                         
                }
                $tr.="</select>";

$nestedData[] = $tr;
```

meu problema esta aqui:

```
$tr.= while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) 
            {
            <option value='$row['nome'];'>$row['nome'];</option>                         
            }
```

Comment: Em vez de `$tr.= while` faça `$tr.= "<option value='".$row['nome']."'>".$row['nome']."</option>";`

Comment: Você tem código não concatenados `
                <option value='$row['nome'];'>$row['nome'];</option>                         
                `

Comment: Pq não você fazer um loop e concatenar a string?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que queira algo assim:

```
$nestedData[] = $row["nomerota"];
$tr="<select size='1'>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
    $tr.= "<option value='$row['nome'];'>$row['nome'];</option>"                         
}
$tr.="</select>";
$nestedData[] = $tr;
```

Você não deve concatenar o `while` e sim o texto e variáveis que estão dentro